# Build an existing PhoneGap project for iOS using PhoneGap Build

Tags: android, ios, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app

I have developed a hybrid app for android using PhoneGap in Windows environment.
This is what i did:
I added android platform after creating a cordova project and then imported it into eclipse and built it and tested it on my android phone.

Now i want to use the same code and build it for iOS using PhoneGap Build service. I can arrange an apple developer certificate but before that i want to make sure whether it is possible to build the existing project for iOS.

Can anyone suggest on this please?

Answer (score 0):

for people looking for an answer to this here, is what i did :

Adobe build only requires a URL of git repo of the project. Once you have got it you can build it for any mobile platforms iOS, Android, Windows, and Blackberry.